# Setting user control's value from web service in asp.net 2010

Tags: javascript, web-services, user-controls

I am calling web service method from the java script and through this web service method I am calling the user control's method. There I want to set the user control's text box value from this web service method. Is it possible in asp.net 2010? If so please help me to get rid of this?
Thanks in advance.
Lenin

Answer (score 0):

Create a public string property 'TextBoxValue' on the usercontrol. Now after you've instantiated it in the webmethod, set the value of the new property. Add some code in the usercontrols page_load which sets the textbox.text of the new public property added.

I think you need to create a wrapper page, which contains the    usercontrol. The usercontrol needs a parent which can load it.

- Add the textstring as a parameter in the url.
- Set    the new public property of de usercontrol to the parameter.
- Execute ajax get-request to new    page.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your instant reply.In my case, the user control is null in web service. Do you have any idea how to instantiate the user control in webservice?